# Google My Business URL not sticking, strange behavior

Tags: google-maps

Hoping other developers on here have seen this issue before, or at least might have some ideas regarding this strange behavior.

I have a client's claimed property in Google My Business, the website ownership has been verified using the same login credentials, and all the Google+ information is complete for the business. **The verification process went smoothly, and it's letting me enter the client details.**

On Google Maps and local Google searches, the details display almost perfectly: company name comes up, phone, address, even reviews. For some odd reason, the URL won't stick.

From Google My Business, under Edit Info, it prompts me to **"Click to enter your website URL."** Upon entering this URL (the same verified URL), the status changes to Pending, and the URL shows up fine on that page. Upon refreshing, the URL disappears, and the same section says **"Click to enter your website URL."**

After entering URL, this shows up:
[Screenshot of URL pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pMWE.jpg)

After hitting refresh, this shows up:
[Screenshot of prompt to enter URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esurz.jpg)

Am I missing something? I don't mind waiting as I understand Google takes some time for these things, but this behavior seems very odd and the fact that it keeps prompting to enter the URL after it's been done worries. me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Apparently Google My Business has free phone support.

https://support.google.com/business/contactflow

I typed in my name, email, and phone number, and within seconds my phone rang. It turns out the URL was getting rejected. It's a pity Google doesn't send you details regarding this rejection, but the support specialist was excellent, and I was up in running in two minutes.

Comment: Can you comment on how the URL was getting rejected? I'm having the exact same problem.